# MYSQL: Multiple tables/joins - Does the join condition need to include the table in the from clause?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a main table:

```
- cam (id, name, type, desc, tenant_id) 
  with information normalized into 3 different tables: 
- cs with columns (cam_id, st_id)
- ot with columns (cam_id, loc_id, tar_id, tenant_id)
- st with columns (id, code, name)
```

please note:

```
- cs.st_id is a foreign key to st.id
- ot.loc_id is a foreign key to st.id, 
- ot.tar_id is a foreign key to st.id
```

My intention is to get the

```
- st.code value for all ot.loc_id and cs.st_id 
  (I am not interested in the id's but the their codes which is stored in table st)
```

This SQL:

```
- select 
    cam.id, cam.name, camp.type, cam.desc, st.code as cs.code 
  from 
    cam
  left join cs on cam.id = cs.cam_id
  left join ot on cam.id = ot.cam_id
  left join st on cam.tenant_id = st.tenant_id;
```

works in that the last join condition to st table makes the st.codes available.
But what do I have to do to get the ot.loc_id codes?? I can't have multiple from clauses right? or multiple tables in from clause ... right?

Or is there no way out but to make separate SQL statements (which may not be performant i.e making an additional call)?

Thanks!

**Take-Away: The join condition does not need to include the table in the from clause! Please see answer below.**

Comment: You might consider a more intuitive naming policy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- No you can't have multiple from clauses
- Yes you can have multiple tables in from clause

For example you could do :

```
select a.id, a.name, a.type, a.desc, b.code as cs.code, b.code
     from cam a, st b, cs c, ot d
     where a.id = c.cam_id
       and a.id = d.cam_id
       and st.id = d.loc_id
       and b.tenant_id = a.tenant_id
```

Or your could simply refer to field in joined tables or views in the select statement.

When you do a join, you "join" the table to your select statement and can access them.

Example with join :

```
select cam.id, cam.name, camp.type, cam.desc, st.code as cs.code, st.code
   from cam
   left join cs on cam.id = cs.cam_id
   left join ot on cam.id = ot.cam_id
   left join st on cam.tenant_id = ot.tenant_id
   left join st st2 on st.id = ot.loc_id;
```

Comment: But I dont want ot.loc_id, but the code that it represents! How do I retrieve that in the same SQL?

Comment: @iyerland Sorry, I did not read that part.. See my update on query.

Comment: Works! I guess the take away is that the join condition does not need to include the table in the from clause :). Thanks!

Comment: @iyerland when you join a table, you select from its values but only the part that match the "on" condition... Check this out for a better comprehension : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Answer (score 0):

Is your intention to join to the `st` table twice?

```
select cam.id, cam.name, camp.type, cam.desc, st.code as cs_code , st.code as loc_code
from cam left join
     cs
     on cam.id = cs.cam_id left join
     ot
     on cam.id = ot.cam_id left join
     st
     on cam.tenant_id = st.id left join
     st stloc
     on ot.loc_id = stloc.id;
```

According to the columns in your tables, `st` doesn't have a `tenant_id` so I changed that to just `id`.